# "Clubbiness" of $\Pi^1_n$ sets

Tags: logic, set-theory, descriptive-set-theory, large-cardinals

I'm sure this is just my google-fu failing me, but: what are sufficient large cardinal axioms to guarantee "Every (boldface) $\Pi^1_n$ set of countable ordinals contains or is disjoint from a club subset of $\omega_1$"?

**EDIT: To clarify, I'm asking about the consistency strength *over ZFC*.**

Here's a very silly upper bound: suppose $L(\mathbb{R})$ is a model of AD; note that every $\Pi^1_n$-sentence with real parameters is absolute between $L(\mathbb{R})$ and $V$. Then let $A\in V$ be a $\Pi^1_n$-set of countable ordinals, via the formula (with real parameters) $\varphi$. By the absoluteness assumption, $\varphi^{L(\mathbb{R})}=A$, so $A\in L(\mathbb{R})$. And since $L(\mathbb{R})\models AD$, $L(\mathbb{R})$ thinks $A$ contains or is disjoint from a club. But inner models compute club-ness correctly, so we're done.

This seems massively overkill to me, though - what is the *right* bound?

Comment: If you looked into Mitchell's old paper: How Weak is A Closed Unbounded Ultrafilter? (Logic Colloquium '80 (Prague, 1980), pp. 209–230), starting from a measurable $\kappa, o(\kappa)=\kappa^{++}$, Radin forcing followed by Levy collapse gives a model such that HOD (with suitable parameters, containing $\mathbb{R}$) gives a model of ZF+DC+club filter on $\omega_1$ is an ultrafilter. It certainly all the sets you want.